# Sencha Cmd 5 - java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, extjs, sencha-cmd

I need to use Sencha Cmd 5 (v5.1.3.61). I am getting an error after `sencha app watch`:

```
Sencha Cmd v5.1.3.61
[WRN] the following remote package repository directories did not initialize properly :
[WRN]    - /home/radoslaw/bin/Sencha/Cmd/5.1.3.61/../repo/pkgs
[WRN]    - /home/radoslaw/bin/Sencha/Cmd/5.1.3.61/../repo/.sencha
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/DatatypeConverter
        at com.sencha.util.StringUtil.toBase64(StringUtil.java:202)
        at com.sencha.tools.generator.DataStoreImpl.get(DataStoreImpl.java:103)
        at com.sencha.tools.generator.Generator$1.doMerge(Generator.java:461)
        at com.sencha.tools.generator.Generator$Mode$3.dispatch(Generator.java:266)
        at com.sencha.tools.generator.Generator.generateFileToFile(Generator.java:446)
        at com.sencha.tools.generator.Generator.generateFileToDir(Generator.java:438)
        at com.sencha.tools.generator.Generator.generateDirToDir(Generator.java:431)
        at com.sencha.tools.generator.Generator.generateDirToDir(Generator.java:426)
        at com.sencha.tools.generator.Generator.generate(Generator.java:145)
        at com.sencha.tools.pkg.LocalRepository.init(LocalRepository.java:131)
        at com.sencha.tools.pkg.LocalRepository.init(LocalRepository.java:185)
        at com.sencha.command.environment.WorkspaceRepository.getLocalRepository(WorkspaceRepository.java:273)
        at com.sencha.command.environment.WorkspaceRepository.getLocalRepository(WorkspaceRepository.java:286)
        at com.sencha.command.environment.FrameworkEnvironment.loadFrameworkPackage(FrameworkEnvironment.java:207)
        at com.sencha.command.environment.AppOrPackageEnvironment.loadFrameworkConfig(AppOrPackageEnvironment.java:52)
        at com.sencha.command.environment.AppEnvironment.<init>(AppEnvironment.java:50)
        at com.sencha.command.environment.BuildEnvironment.load(BuildEnvironment.java:100)
        at com.sencha.command.environment.BuildEnvironment.load(BuildEnvironment.java:124)
        at com.sencha.command.environment.BuildEnvironment.load(BuildEnvironment.java:70)
        at com.sencha.command.Sencha.loadBuildEnvironment(Sencha.java:426)
        at com.sencha.command.Sencha.main(Sencha.java:128)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:581)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
        ... 21 more
```

Operating System: Linux Mint 20 Cinnamon

Linux Karnel: 5.4.0-26-generic

Java version:

```
openjdk version "11.0.7" 2020-04-14
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.7+10-post-Ubuntu-3ubuntu1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 11.0.7+10-post-Ubuntu-3ubuntu1, mixed mode, sharing)
```

I understand that boils down to the Java version.
The solutions I found did not come down to the same problem.
Has anyone encountered such a problem? What will be the simplest solution?

Comment: Nope, but I would suggest to give it with java8 a try. Or use latest Cmd version, but I am not sure if Ext5 is still supported. Details here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43574426/how-to-resolve-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-javax-xml-bind-jaxbexception-in-j

Comment: Resolved. I just use sencha cmd 7...